# iOS Pointer to Pointer NSMutableDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

I've written this piece of code:

```
- (void) addKey:(NSString *)key inMessage:(DEMessage *)message to:(NSMutableDictionary * __autoreleasing *)to
{
    if ([message getPropertyByPath:key]) {
        [*to setObject:@([[message getPropertyValue:key] floatValue]) forKey:key];
    }
}
```

Which I call by:

```
NSMutableDictionary *statistics = [NSMutableDictionary new];
[self addKey:@"Yellow" inMessage:message to:&statistics];
[self addKey:@"Red" inMessage:message to:&statistics];
[self addKey:@"Matches" inMessage:message to:&statistics];
[self addKey:@"Goals" inMessage:message to:&statistics];
[self addKey:@"GoalsPerMatch" inMessage:message to:&statistics];
[self addKey:@"Faults" inMessage:message to:&statistics];
[self addKey:@"Expelled" inMessage:message to:&statistics];
 _statistics = [statistics copy];
```

The method I wrote is just so remove code duplication. The only problem is when I build it with a Development certificate everything is fine, but when I use a production/ad hoc certificate it crashes on this piece.

The error I receive is segmentation fault 11. Which says to me that I am using memory which is not mine. I don't get this...

So the question is: "Why does my program crash on a production/ad hoc certificate and why is my code incorrect?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: The question is: why are you passing a pointer-to-pointer? :o

Comment: Also, what's that `@([[message getPropertyValue:key] floatValue])`? It's entirely redundant, unreadable and unnecessary.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant It is not unreadable for somewhat who uses this library and this is beside the point of the question

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant My C skills are somewhat left in the dark. But I saw that NSError used a pointer to pointer Could you elaborate why it uses it there ?

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant And if I do not use the pointer to pointer the method would work just fine but is it correct?

Comment: @MouNtant, when you see NSError used that way it's to pass by reference in an "out" parameter. Wether it's an NSError or an NSDictionary, it must be treated differently than other pointers. For example, you must check to make sure the pointer is not NULL before using it - this is likely your crash. Why not just return the NSDictionary? This would be much simpler and less error prone.

Comment: @MouNtant `NSError` is immutable. You can't pass in an initialized `NSError` object and have it filled by another method, hence the method needs to allocate and initialize an `NSError` object itself, and set a pointer (through a pointer-to-pointer) in the calling function. One can, however, pass in an initialized `NSMutableArray` to a method and have it filled just fine.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Thank you bro That was clear. What is still the problem is the difference between development and production certificate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's the use of the `(NSMutableDictionary * __autoreleasing *)` parameter. It's not necessary, and I'm guessing that it's causing the `NSMutableDictionary` to be overreleased. It would be better written as:

```
NSMutableDictionary* stats = [NSMutableDictionary new];
NSArray* keys = @[@"Yellow", @"Red", @"Matches"]; //etc.
for(NSString* k in keys){
    NSNumber* value = [message getPropertyByPath:k];
    if (value) {
        [stats setObject:value forKey:k];
    }
}
_statistics = [statistics copy];
```

It's probably triggered by the something in the difference between debug and release builds.

Comment: The use of pointer pointer is instead not correct. I've fixed this. And your statement about being triggered by something different is most likely true. But where can I find this? So I can see what the difference are between production and developement